# spritekit my player node doesn't move according to my touches?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touches

I've been trying to figure out this bug in my code that whenever my player node is to the most left/right side of my screen it tends to behave weirdly i.e. it'd go off to the right/left even though when i've touched left/right

Here's my code:

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let action = SKAction.moveTo(x:location.x, duration: 0.45)
        if location.x > (player?.position.x)! {
            player?.run(action)
            moveLeft = false
        } else {
            player?.run(action)
            moveLeft = true
        }
    }
    canMove = true
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    canMove = false
}
```

Here's the moveleft in Player.swift

```
// Move function
func move(left: Bool) {
    if left {
        position.x -= 10
        // Set boundary to minX so it wont go below
        if position.x < minX {
            position.x = minX
        }

    } else {
        position.x += 10

        // Set boundary to maxX so player cannot move over the right boundary
        if position.x > maxX {
            position.x = maxX
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you call an action on your player. It looks like func move get never called. Also canMove and moveLeft/moveRight never comes into play. I only can see in your code, that when a touch began on a x position the player will move to the x-position only one time.

Comment: Show me where you call the player.move() and provide more code please.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your actions are stacking on top of each other, so every time you touch, you add a new action.  If you touched left, right, left your character would act erratic. To combat this, assign a key `player?.run(action, withKey:"moving")` (Do not assign different keys for left and right, use only 1 key for moving in any direction)

2)You are touching based on left or right of the player, when the player is all the way to the left, even touching the left side of the screen will move him right.  You may want to switch this to simply if x is negative go left, if x is positive go right (Assuming the center of your scene is (0,0)

3)Not sure when `move(left:Bool)` is getting called,  I am not seeing it in the code.

This is not even needed,  I would avoid having this bool check all together.